# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined (live searching)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, i have this code that retrieves movies from api and im trying to implement live searching. I created an if statement to check the input but every time i put the first character in the input field I get the filter undefined error. How can I fix this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SearchMovie = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [movie, setmovie] = useState("");
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const key = "xxxxxxxx";
  const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${movie}&apikey=${key}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [movie]);

  const getData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const response = await data.json();
    setState(response.Search);
    console.log(response.Search);
  };
  
  const updateSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const getSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setmovie(search);
    setSearch("");
  }

    if(search.length > 0) {
  setState(state.filter((i)=>{
      return i.Title.match(search)
  }))
} 
 
  return (
    <div>
     <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search-bar"
          value={search}
          onChange={updateSearch}
        />
        <button className="search-button" type="submit">
          Search
        </button>
      </form> 
           {(state || []).map((details) => (  
              <>
       <p>{details.Title}</p>
       <p>{details.Year}</p>
       <img src={details.Poster} alt=""/>
       </>
     ))}   
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchMovie;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have call `filter` on `undefined`. Because you have `setState(response.Search)`. I think your result search is undefined. Let's check.

```
  const getData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const response = await data.json();
    setState(response.Search ? response.Search : []); 
    //or
    //if (response.Search) setState(response.Search)
    console.log(response.Search);
  };
```

Comment: well I don't think you need to do the if statement there because if it's empty its will send an empty array I am pretty sure like most API when there is zero values he returns the empty array or object

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: Could you show us data in search result? I mean ` console.log(response);`

Comment: it returns all api data, just when i uncomment the if statement for live searchi get the error

Comment: how does api data look like?

Comment: {
"Search": [
{
"Title": "Alita: Battle Angel",
"Year": "2019",
"imdbID": "tt0437086",
"Type": "movie",
"Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQzYWYwYjctY2JhZS00NTYzLTllM2UtZWY5ZTk0NmYwYzIyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzgxODM4NjM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
}
],
"totalResults": "1",
"Response": "True"
}

Comment: Did you try to apply my function getData above to test?

Comment: Yeah I did and got tundefined

Comment: Try rebuild and clear cached. Also, you should not call setState in function, it will cause infinity loop, try put it in useEffect and dependencies on some variable like:     useEffect(() => {
        if(search.length > 0) {
            setState(state.filter((i)=>{
                console.log('in');
                return i.Title.match(search)
            }))
        }
    }, [state]);